# Making use of Clock in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a noob in the section of mobile app development. I tried to use kivy.clock.Clock to schedule a task, that adds 1 to the current text(integer) in label inside simple app I created.Simply I need to update value in Label once a three seconds. The starting value of label text is 4. And also I need to print the current value that is in Label when I pressed the button in my app. But however it doesn't work. Can someone help me to figure out the fault that I made? I will post the entire codes in main.py and my.kv files below.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyGrid(Widget):
    txtLbl = ObjectProperty(None)
    bTn = ObjectProperty(None)
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.printNum, 3)
    def printNum(self, *args):
        self.txtLbl.text = str(int(self.txtLbl.text)+1)
    def myFunc(self):
        print('Current number in Label is ', self.txtLbl.text)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()


code in my.kv
=============


<MyGrid>:
    GridLayout:
        txtLbl:txtlbl
        bTn:btn
        size:root.width-100, root.height-100
        pos:50, 50
        cols:1
        Label:
            id:txtlbl
            text:'4'

        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            Button:
                text:'Print current number'
                id:btn
                on_press:root.myFunc()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code that does what I think you want:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

kv = '''
<MyGrid>:
    txtLbl:txtlbl
    bTn:btn
    GridLayout:
        size:root.width-100, root.height-100
        pos:50, 50
        cols:1
        Label:
            id:txtlbl
            text:'4'

        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            Button:
                text:'Print current number'
                id:btn
                on_press:root.myFunc()
'''

class MyGrid(Widget):
    txtLbl = ObjectProperty(None)
    bTn = ObjectProperty(None)
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.printNUm, 3)
    def printNum(self, *args):
        self.txtLbl.text = str(int(self.txtLbl.text)+1)
    def myFunc(self):
        print('Current number in Label is ', self.txtLbl.text)
    def update(self, dt):
        self.txtLbl.text = str(int(self.txtLbl.text) + 1)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        mygrid = MyGrid()
        Clock.schedule_interval(mygrid.update, 3)
        return mygrid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Note that the `txtLbl:txtlbl` and `bTn:btn` in the `kv` have been moved up so that they corresponds to the `txtLbl = ObjectProperty(None)` and `bTn = ObjectProperty(None)` of the `MyGrid` class.

The `Clock` is used to schedule an `update` method every 3 seconds. That method updates the text of the `Label` by incrementing its value by one.

I used `Builder.load_string()` just for my own convenience.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This was my first question in stackoverflow. I was helpless while trying to find a remedy for the bug. You proved me I chose the best place to ask for help. Thanks again.